# Copy xml being displayed in web browser and save as .xml

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a requirement where I have to open a url in browser which will show an .xml file in response (in the browser) and I have to save the file in my local directory with extension as .xml i have already tried with action class to perform Ctrl + save but neither error nor output is coming. Tried with action class but it is showing vh_ctrl cannot be resolved.

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: I did tried some approach and have mentioned in the Q as well. I have tried with Action class and with Robot class but it was not working properly. I cannot share the code as I'm not having access for the same outside my organization.

Comment: You need to post the code attempts you have tried and what the results were including any error messages if you want us to be able to help you. SO guidelines state that you need to provide an [mcve] which you have not done. Failing to provide that will likely result in your question being closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use java, you can try package `java.awt.robot` to send `Ctrl+S` keys.

For selenium `Actions` class should not support to do that.

Comment: I tried using robot class but for KeyEvent.VK_ENTER it is throwing VK_ENTER cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to compliment the answer but can not do that, so I am writing my reply as an answer.
Have you imported `java.awt.event.KeyEvent;`
You will need this class for `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`

I have used Robot for uploading the attachment on webpage through Selenium and it works for me fine.

Comment: Yes i did imported the same package.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which programming language you are using, but since Selenium is not designed for interacting with the OS I would recommend that you avoid using Selenium altogether.  Just use the capability of your programming language to make an HTTP request to the server to retrieve the target file directly.  Or just use wget or cURL.

Comment: Tried with servlet call but was no getting any response so finally moved to selenium and tried to save the file.